# How to testing the equality of variables in Assembler?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have problem with testing the equality of variables. In this case it works, it skip this "do something", it go to next like i want:

```
b dw 5

mov eax, [b]
 cmp eax, 5
 je next
 ;do something
 next:
```

But , if i set for example 6 instead of 5 it won't skip "do something":

```
b dw 6

mov eax, [b]
 cmp eax, 6
 je next
 ;do something
 next:
```

(Using NASM)

Answer (score 3):

The size of your variable relative to how you're using it is wrong:

```
b dw 6

mov eax, [b]
cmp eax, 6
```

When you use `dw` you declare a *word*-sized variable, which is 16 bits on x86. The `eax` register is 32 bits (a doubleword), so with `mov eax,[b]` you're loading the word at `b` *and* the word direcly following `b` in memory, whatever that may contain.

Either change your declaration of `b` to `b dd 6`, or use a zero-extending `mov` (`movzx eax, word [b]`).

Comment: this? 

 `b dd 6
  mov ax, [b] 
 cmp ax, 6 
 je next 
 ;do something 
 next:`

It again won't skip "do something"

Comment: I didn't realize that you really didn't have anything in between the variable declaration and the `mov`. You should not have data in your code path. Regarding your comment: if you load `b` into `ax` instead of `eax` you can keep using `dw` for `b`, since `ax` is 16 bits (assuming that you don't have any 32-bit accesses to `b` elsewhere in your code).

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I just jump over "`b dd 6`" and it work